# PHP passing values from one function to another but not loop through the views? (CodeIgniter, PHP 7)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3, php-7

When a user logs into my site, they will get directed to a function `confirmTicket` inside of a controller (named `ticketController`). This requires an array named data that is created inside of a function called `addTicket`. However, this data is then used in a view with a form. This form should be able to confirm that the user is happy with what is being stored in the database, and this form is sent to `ticketController/confirmTicket`. The first command inside of this is to get the array, so the program loops between these pages without ever going anywhere. Here is the code:

User lands here, inside the `confirmTicket` function:

```
public function confirmTicket() {
        $data = $this->addTicketIndex();
        //code to load confirmAdd view never gets executed due to above command, but can't come before as $data is required
}
```

This means that addTicketIndex() is run:

```
function addTicketIndex() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('addTickets');
}
```

This loads the addTickets view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Submit a new issue </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <?php echo "Welcome back, ". $this->session->userdata('forename'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        echo form_open("TicketController/addTicket");
    ?>
    <div id="container">
        <label for="summary"> Please enter the issue you are experiencing, be as specific as possible (assets numbers of PC's etc.) but please refrain from entering any personal information such as passwords. </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="issue" placeholder="Enter your issue here">
        <br>
    </div>
</body>
</head>
```

This opens the `addTicket()` function:

```
   public function addTicket() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('issue', 'Summary', 'required|max_length[500]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            echo "It appears you have not entered an issue or that your issue is over 500 characters";
            $this->load->view('addTickets');
        } else {
            $temp = $this->input->post('issue');
            $data["ticket"] = array (
                'priority' => '1',
                'summary' => $this->input->post('issue'),
                'status' => 'Submitted',
                'category' => exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/ci/assets/machineLearning.py machineLearning $temp 2>&1"),
                'itemsRequired' => ' ',
                'lastUpdate' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s'),
                'ownerID' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                'managerID' => 'tech'
            );
            $this->load->view("confirmAdd");
        }
    }
```

This then loads the `confirmAdd` view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Are you sure? </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "Please help us improve our Machine Learning by selecting the appropriate category from the drop down box below. It is in your interest to select the closest category so your issue can be resolved as soon as possible. <br>";
    ?>

    <?php echo form_open('ticketController/confirmTicket'); ?>
    <label for="cngCategory"> Category </label><br>
        <select name="newCategory">
            <option value="idCard">ID Card</option>
            <option value="printer">Printer</option>
            <option value="byod">BYOD (Bring Your Own Device) </option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
            <option value="desktop_pc">Desktop</option>
            <option value="forgotten_password">Forgotten Password </option>
            <option value="lost_work">Lost Work </option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">

</body>
</html>
```

Which then directs me to the `confirmTicket` function where I wish to use `$data` to make a call to the database and insert the ticket, but, as the first line is `$data = $this->addTicketIndex();`, the cycle begins all over again. Is there a way to do these steps only ONCE and then stop so processing can continue over?

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Have tried this doesn't work in my case, as far as I can tell. I load the view and data from inside of `addTicket` and yeah that works fine, but then I need the data inside of `confirmTicket` again. The way to do this is through the `$data = $this->addTicketIndex();` line, right? Which will start the redirection all over again? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 also, by calling the `addTicket` function from the confirm view, means that `$data` is set again and then the view is loaded again - another loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning the data. Example only below

```
public function confirmTicket() {
    $data = $this->addTicketIndex();
    echo $data['hello'];
}

function addTicketIndex() {
    $data['hello'] = 'Test';

    return $data;
}
```